# Wordpress plugin that assigns tags to categories

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody know a WordPress plugin that assigns tags to a category ?

In WordPress I need to link some tags to a category and when somebody enters a new post to determine the category, by the tags used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

"Categories to Tags Converter Importer", Version 0.5, By wordpressdotorg.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need. I need a plugin that can assign some tags to a category, not to convert between the 2 entities.

Answer (score -1):

This plugin enables you to organize tags (or categories, or custom terms) in groups. The group membership is saved in the native WP table field term_group, so it won't create additional tables in the database. The plugin comes with a configurable tag cloud where tags are displayed in tabs sorted by the groups.

[tag-group plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tag-groups/)

Answer (score -1):

This plug-in will allow you to create a list of tags and assign them to a specific post type:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-tag-insert/